# Segmentation fault (core dumped) by the programming solver

Tags: segmentation-fault, jupyter-notebook, coredump, drake

This piece of example code:
'''
    import numpy as np
    import pydrake.solvers.mathematicalprogram as mp
    from pydrake.solvers.ipopt import IpoptSolver
    def foo(x):
        return np.sign(x)

```
prog = mp.MathematicalProgram()
x = prog.NewContinuousVariables(1)
prog.AddConstraint(foo, [1.], [1.], vars=x)
prog.AddLinearCost(1 * x[0])
result = mp.Solve(prog, np.array([10.]), None)
print(result.is_success())
print(result.GetSolution(x))
```

'''
returns the error: Segmentation fault (core dumped), when I run it under termial opened by the jupyter notebook, provided by the course: http://underactuated.csail.mit.edu/Spring2019/install_drake_docker.html.
(while the code itself already proved right here,https://github.com/RobotLocomotion/drake/issues/12410)

Answer (score 0):

With docker image drake-20190129, this code cannot run. Specifically the line `mp.Solve(prog, np.array([10.]), None)` is problematic. Back then Drake doesn't support this function. You will need to replace this line with `result = prog.Solve()`.

And after replacing the line, my kernel dies.

I wouldn't recommend using the docker drake-20190129 for your code. Specifically the line `prog.AddConstraint(foo, [1.], [1.], vars=x)` was not supported back then (2019, Jan, 29). I normally use the most up-to-date version of drake, as explained in https://drake.mit.edu/python_bindings.html

Comment: Yes, not supported even in version 20190423. btw, you finally reproduce my fault :)

Comment: FWIW We have nightly docker images published that have Drake code: https://hub.docker.com/r/robotlocomotion/drake/tags

However, this will not have the underactuated class materials.